# Evaluating the derivative of a polynomial

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + \cdots + x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - ax + b$

We wish to compute $f'(1)$. The way I did this was to differentiate term by term, and then pair the terms of the form $-(2m + 1)x^{2m} + (2m) x^{2m-1}$ to get $-1$ summed $n-1$ times to get a $1-n$ term. Considering the first and last terms, we see that $2n$ and $-a$ contribute a term. So we get $f'(1) = n+1-a$

My book just states that $f'(1) = n-1+2-a$. They might have a quicker way than my reasoning, and I am not sure where the $+2$ comes from. Does anyone see how the book did it?

Comment: $f(x)=-ax+b+\sum_{k=2}^{2n}(-1)^kx^k$ hence $f'(x)=-a+\sum_{k=2}^{2n}(-1)^kkx^{k-1}$ and $$f'(1)=-a+\sum_{k=2}^{2n}(-1)^kk=-a+2+\sum_{k=3}^{2n}(-1)^kk=-a+2-\sum_{j=2}^n(2j-1)+\sum_{j=2}^n(2j)$$ and we get the result.

Comment: Or maybe $f(x)=(-ax +b)-(1-x)+[1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots +x^{2n}]$. The sum in square brackets is $\frac{1+x^{2n+1}}{1+x}$, easy to differentiate.

Answer (score 5):

They are just pairing neighboring terms the opposite way from you, namely $$(2k)1^{2k-1}-(2k-1)1^{2k-2}=2k-(2k-1)=1$$ There are $n-1$ full pairs, and $2-a$ is the derivative of $x^2-ax$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + \cdots + x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - ax + b$,
$f(x) = x^{2n} - x^{2n-1} + \cdots + x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1 + x - 1 - ax + b$,
so $f(x) = \frac{x^{2n+1}+1}{x+1} + x - 1 - ax + b
= \frac{x^{2n+1}+1}{x+1} + x(1-a) - 1 + b$.

Differentiating,
$f'(x) = \frac{(2n+1)x^{2n}(x+1)-(x^{2n+1}+1)}{(x+1)^2} + 1-a
= \frac{2nx^{2n+1}+(2n+1)x^{2n}-1}{(x+1)^2} + 1-a$.

Setting $x=1$,
$f'(1) = \frac{2n+(2n+1)-1}{4}+1-a
=n+1-a$.

At no extra charge,
$f(1) = \frac{1+1}{1+1} + (1-a) - 1 + b
= 1 - a + b$
(which you can see from cancellation, 
but it's nice to have a check).

Comment: Very good, but, in my opinion, more complicated than the others because of the need to invoke the quotient rule.